# echo inside text area: Anyone know why this form isn't working properly on live server? it works on my local host

Tags: php, html, forms, post, echo

This is my code below, it works when I run it on my localhost, but since I have uploaded it to my site via CPanel, it just loads the url www.wordle.net/advanced and shows a blank screen, any ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

```
$text =  array_values($text[0]);
$text2 = implode(",", $text); 
$finalText = strip_tags($text2);
    ?>


<form action="http://www.wordle.net/advanced" method="POST">
<textarea name="text" style="display:none">
<?php echo $finalText ?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/></form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: blank screen = something blew up and you have all debug options turned off. go into php.ini and enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting`, and try again.

Comment: And what should it display?

Comment: rather new to PHP, what is php.ini @MarcB

Comment: php's master settings file.

Comment: whats var_dump($text); display if its okay

Also your missing ';' on this line <?php echo $finalText ?>
should be <?php echo $finalText; ?>

Comment: @LukeHardiman Doesn't makes a difference if there is a semicolon or not! [The closing tag implies it!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284131/3933332)

Comment: How do i view the php.ini file so that I can change it? added
   <? phpinfo(); ?>
to my code which displays the php.ini file but i cannot edit it?

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks for that learnt something new, didn't realise it was optional

Comment: Just checked the php.ini file and both of those things are enabled @MarcB

Comment: @JCAnthony: then possibly the errors are being redirect to a log file. check the server's error log, or if it's logging php stuff elsewhere

Comment: @MarcB checked that and there are no errors! thanks for the help anyway! The site I'm working on for a project is www.fastfilm.co.uk, if you search for a film, and then pick the one out of the drop down on the next screen, then press submit on the next screen, it should send the movies reviews to wordle but just loads nothing instead! by all means give it a go yourself! Excuse the awful UI at the moment!